# using Usercake to discover information about a user

Tags: php, mysql, usercake

Okay so I have what I think is a weird problem. I'm using Usercake [link to page](http://usercake.com/) as my form of user management . Everything works great and for someone who'd not to advanced in php/ db administration it's awesome. I am now attempting to change the look of a page based if a user is logged in or not.

So from this [link in the forum](http://usercake.com/thread.php?id=265) I am attempting to change a pannel on the page if the user is logged in the first code snippet is my modified version of that i'd like to use

```
if (isUserLoggedIn()){
  print('
    <ul class="login">
                    <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>Hello
  ');
   echo $loggedInUser->username . " Good 2 c ya!" ;
   print(' </li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
            <a id="open" class="open" href="#">Log In | Register</a>
            <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
          </ul>
            </div> <!-- / top -->
    </div> <!--panel -->
 ');
}else{ ... do everything normal 
}
```

now I know that `isUserLoggedIn()` because when I am logged in the display is changed however the place where `$loggedInUser->username` is left empty. any reason as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Notes:  I have Included 'models/config.php' in the script and have used `$loggedInUser->user_id` on other pages with no problem but for some reason that doesn't seem to work here either. I have also logged In and out a few times to make sure this is not working as I've read this can be a hang up for whatever reason. Also this code is inside a my_script / my_function which is included in a larger page using php `require 'my_script'`  if that would make a difference 
Again anyhelp in this would be great

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest confirming the require script has the correct path, and adding in `$session_start()` to confirm that the session is correctly started.

Following that, turn on php errors and use echos within the usercake script to confirm pages and functions are calling correctly.

Good luck